# wp_footer hook only working on homepage not in other pages

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development, footer, wp-head

I  try to output a javascript code in `wp_footer` hook but it is not printed in all pages it is working in home page only.

I have checked for the presence of `wp_footer();` function in `footer.php` it is present but still i couldn't get this work.

I have deactivated all plugins. I have tried it with default themes like `twenty_thirteen`

Whatever i have checked is the problem arising area but it looks there is no problem from those, looks very strange.

But this happens only in live site not in localhost.

Is there some other place to check for the problem?

What might be the problem?

Why it is not printing in any other pages except the homepage?

Here is the sample code

```
function test(){
?>
<script>
console.log("testing");
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_footer','test');
```

One more note `wp_head` hook also performing the same way as it prints only on homepage not in any other pages.

Comment: Press control and F5 on your keyboard to clear your browser cache. Also clear all other caches from any cache plugin that you have installed. This seems to be a pure cache problem

Comment: Thanks for the hint. No there is no cache plugin in the site. this might not be a problem i think. Let me know @PieterGoosen

Comment: Any solution? I am having the same problem